# Custom PDO Database class for session and everything else

Tags: php, database, session, pdo

I have a well tested custom PDO Database class. And there is something what drives me crazy. Do you use the same class (same connection) for your database driven session handler class and the rest of your web application, or have two database connection opened for session and for the rest of the web application? I am using dependency injector. I really appreciate any answer/suggestions.

Comment: the only time you'd want multiple connections if you're connecting to different db servers, and/or the same db server with different credentials.

Comment: Thank you Marc. This means that I can pass an existing db instance to dbsession handler? Recently I had problems with this e.g. begintransaction runninquery in session class etc. and doing db queries somwhere else it starts behave really od. I am really thinking dropping thid pdo encapsulated inside custom class thing. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: well, how you go about it is entirely up to you. but if you start holding open multiple connections, you can run into all kinds of problems. e.g. start a transaction on connection #1, then somehow start using connection #2, where the transaction won't exist. you can also trivially trigger deadlocks between the multiple sessions.

Comment: Commonly the sessions are stored in the same database as the business data. So there is one database connection only necessary. I can't think of a scenario where two connections for each named purpose makes sense either. Additionially it decreases the performance as you have to establish two database connections. The mentioned dependency injection has nothing to do with an amount of database connections.

Comment: @MarcB absolutely! I do not want to look smart but what you descriped also happens with single connection. The wodoo magic happens in `session_set_save_handler()`. I had error in situtations where outside of session handler `$database->beginTransaction(), $database->query(...), $database->endTransaction()` and at the same time in the session handler `$database->beginTransaction(), $database->query(...), $database->endTransaction()` kicks in. Because of this uncontrollable behaviour of session_set_save_handler() the database class holding the connection produces errors.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial, it starts a new database connection in session_set_save_handler() https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/the-php-anthology-101-essential-tips-tricks-hacks-2nd-edition/preview/how-do-i-store-sessions-in-a-database-c9a44a5 . No words about what if I want to use the same database connection for anything else than session outside of session_set_save_handler().